# How to build rootfs.tar from RHEL UBI image (pulled with podman)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, rhel, wsl-2, podman, ubi

If I pull a RHEL UBI image like so (On Windows using cygwin and podman),

`$podman pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi`

Is there a command I can run on the host system (Windows) to create a file on the host (Windows) that would be a `rootfs.tar` of the UBI image that was pulled?

---

I want to then use that `rootfs.tar` to run on the Windows host under WSL2.

If anyone has done this or if there is another way to fetch the UBI image as a `rootfs.tar`, it would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with docker containers but it should be the same thing:

```
podman export -o rootfs.tar <container-numeric-id>
```

Then import the `rootfs.tar` in WSL with:

```
wsl --import <DistributionName aka RHEL> <Install location aka c:\wsl\RHEL> <FileName aka rootfs.tar>
```

Here is a link to the documentation: [podman-export](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-export.1.html)

Bare in mind that, depending on the container you used and what you want to achieve with it, you may need to take some additionally steps to make it a fully working WSL distro like installing the `sudo` package, creating a new user and setting up `/etc/wsl.conf` to someting like this:

```
## wsl.conf
[automount]
enabled = true
mountfstab = true
root = /mnt/
options = metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=11,case=off

[network]
generatehosts = true
generateresolvconf = true
hostname = RHEL

[interop]
enabled = true
appendwindowspath = true

[user]
default = <your_new_user_name>
```

You can find details about `wsl.conf` here [wsl-config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config)